# R is passing list index value as numeric, how to force pass as characters

Tags: r, casting, character, r-factor

I have some code which passes a list containing some strings to another function. Thing is the new function doesn't use the string associated with the index, but rather uses the index number.

How do I force it to use the string value behind the index value?

My code

```
  for (i in 1:length(cList)) {

    cList[i] <- GetData(cList[i], StartMonth, StartNumberofMonth, StartYear, EndMonth, EndNumberofMonth, EndYear)

      }


GetData <- function (TickerID, StartMonth, StartNumberofMonth, StartYear, EndMonth, EndNumberofMonth, EndYear) {

  url1 <- "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="
  url2 <- paste0(TickerID, "&a=", StartMonth-1, "&b=")
  url3 <- paste0(StartNumberofMonth, "&c=", StartYear)
  url4 <- paste0("&d=", EndMonth -1, "&e=", EndNumberofMonth)
  url5 <- paste0("&f=", EndYear, "&g=d&ignore=.csv")
  #/ Generate CSV URL link
      url.final <- paste(url1, url2, url3, url4, url5)

}
```

When I write print (`url.final`) I get

```
[1] "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s= 4&a=1&b= 1&c=2013 &d=1&e=1 &f=2015&g=d&ignore=.csv"
```

TickerID List

```
[1] BABA
Levels: ABBV ABEV ACT BABA KMI LFC MA ORCL TSM UPS
```

As you can see, the index value has been used, not the string behind it. I already tried casting `TickerID` with `as.character`, with the same result (not working).

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for but fix GetData function: it lacks of a curly brackets at the end.

Comment: What is cList? What is the call to `GetData` you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is `cList` is a list, so you cannot cast directly to character the component you get with `cList[i]`, because this is also a list!

If you have `myList = list(a=1, b=2, c=3)`, `myList[1]` and `myList[1:2`] are lists (try `class(myList[1])` and `class(myList[1:2])` to check). On the other hand, `myList[[1]]` provides you with the content of the first element of the list, which is numeric (try `class(myList[[1]])`).

To keep your approach, you can unlist your list (with just one element) using this:

```
cList[i] <- GetData(as.character(unlist(cList[i])), StartMonth, StartNumberofMonth, StartYear, EndMonth, EndNumberofMonth, EndYear)
```

or index directly the contents of the i-th element of the list using the doble brace:

```
cList[i] <- GetData(as.character(cList[[i]]), StartMonth, StartNumberofMonth, StartYear, EndMonth, EndNumberofMonth, EndYear)
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to first unlist the list? I though the list would automatically return the index character value, and not it's corresponding level value

Comment: I added some more details in the answer.